# Error while using WebKit .NET

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to use the third-party class library called WebKit .NET to make a web browser. For some reason, there is an error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning     There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "WebKitBrowser, Version=0.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b967213f6d29a3be, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

I would like someone to tell me how to fix it, or, bring me to a different third-party class library for making web browsers in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the x64 version. NuGet can fetch that for you.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: What is it called?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem description correctly, the library you are using has been compiled for the x86 architecture, while your project is not targeting any specific architecture, it is just being compiled to MSIL.  I am not sure why this is a problem, and it may be that it is not: What you are seeing is a warning, not an error, so it may be that you can disregard it.

In any case, have you tried the [`System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) class?  It might represent a much easier way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: The web browser control is not very fast and does not run Gmail.

Comment: what? the web browser control doesn't run Gmail? That control uses IE installed on your machine. I will be surprised if you cant open gmail in IE 11. Unless you are using XP then yea it probably won't work on IE 7